# Current controller and action from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At this time I'm trying to know what is the current action and controller from the update action and depending of that I redirect an especific file

```
def editpaso1
end

def editpaso2
end

def editpaso3
end    

def create
    @caracterizacion = Caracterizacion.new(caracterizacion_params)

    if @caracterizacion.save
        redirect_to editpaso1_persona_caracterizacion_path(@persona, @caracterizacion), notice: 'Paso1 Finalizado Correctamente'
    else
        render action: 'new'
    end
end

def update
    if @caracterizacion.update(caracterizacion_params)
        if controller_name.to_s == 'caracterizaciones' && action_name.to_s == 'editpaso1'
            redirect_to editpaso2_persona_caracterizacion_path(@persona, @caracterizacion), notice: 'Paso2 Finalizado Correctamente'
        elsif controller_name.to_s == 'caracterizaciones' && action_name.to_s == 'editpaso2'
            redirect_to editpaso3_persona_caracterizacion_path(@persona, @caracterizacion), notice: 'Paso3 Finalizado Correctamente'
        elsif controller_name.to_s == 'caracterizaciones' && action_name.to_s == 'editpaso3'
            redirect_to @caracterizacion, notice: 'Caracterizacion was successfully updated.'
        end
    else
        if controller_name.to_s == 'caracterizaciones' && action_name.to_s == 'editpaso1'
            render action: 'editpaso1'
        elsif controller_name.to_s == 'caracterizaciones' && action_name.to_s == 'editpaso2'
            render action: 'editpaso2'
        elsif controller_name.to_s == 'caracterizaciones' && action_name.to_s == 'editpaso3'
            render action: 'editpaso3'
        end
    end
end
```

as you can see, first the create redirect to editpaso1, this is working ok, but the problem is when the app try to redirect to the editpaso2 because give this error

```
Missing template caracterizaciones/update, application/update with...
```

and redirect to this url

```
http://localhost:3000/personas/3/caracterizaciones/12
```

but should redirect to this one

```
http://localhost:3000/personas/3/caracterizaciones/12/editpaso2
```

SO I think the problem is when validates the current action

This way I have the others files

```
resources :personas do
    resources :caracterizaciones do

        member do
            get :editpaso1
            get :editpaso2
            get :editpaso3
        end
    end
end
```

and all the edit's files use the update action, I did it like this just because the table has 126 fields

sorry for my english, is not my native language

Thanks for your help

Comment: 1) why do you check controller name? 2) you are in the update action, so the action name will always be `update`

Comment: That's because I made like a wizard and are 3 steps to fill all the table so I need to validate the update where is gonna redirect depending of the current step for example: http://localhost:3000/personas/3/caracterizaciones/12/editpaso1 use update action and should redirect to http://localhost:3000/personas/3/caracterizaciones/12/editpaso2 and later should redirect to http://localhost:3000/personas/3/caracterizaciones/12/editpaso3

Comment: still no need to check the controller name. Use a hidden field to know at which step your user is, you cant rely on the action name

Comment: Can you tell me please how this hidden field would work or what exactly do you mean